# How to create an xml feed from an asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, xml, feed

I am building a web application in which i will be using another websites services.
That website is asking me to provide it with "the URL of the XML feed". I am unable to understand, what is the URL of the XML feed and how to create a XML feed, as I am new to this.

Any code walkthroughs or articles will be helpfull. 
Please help !

Comment: Are you exposing a webservice as well?  Is it asking you for your services WSDL?

Comment: no i am not exposing any kind of web services.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what is being asked for is an [Atom Feed](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4287.xhtml). Building an atom feed in ASP.NET is pretty easy to do yourself, but existing libraries like [Atom.NET](http://atomnet.sourceforge.net/) will make it much easier to get going and will also help you follow the standard as closely as possible.